# What is Pruning & Truncation in Decision Trees?

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm, pruning, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

### Pruning & Truncation

As per my understanding

**Truncation:** Stop the tree while it is still growing so that it may not end up with leaves containing very low data points. One way to do this is to set a minimum number of training inputs to use on each leaf.

**Pruning** is a technique in machine learning and search algorithms that reduces the size of decision trees by removing sections of the tree that provide little power to classify instances.

> - Can somebody explain the in-detailed implementation of these techniques in GBDT frameworks like XGBoost/LightGBM.
> - Which parameters are used in implementing these techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. `xgboost` has nice explanation in the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html).

Reading the original papers is always great idea. Here's one for [LGBM](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6907-lightgbm-a-highly-efficient-gradient-boosting-decision-tree.pdf) and here's one for [XGBoost](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf).

As for dessert, here's `catboost` [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09516.pdf).

Boosting is by far one of the most important concepts in hard machine learning. It's good to know it by heart.